# Can I add a CustomXmlPart to my presentation without storing the XML for it in a file?

Tags: c#, .net, powerpoint, openxml, openxml-sdk

**TLDR;** Please either confirm that the 2nd code snippit is the accepted method for creating a **CustomXmlPart** or show me another less tedious method.

---

So I'm trying to embed some application data in some of the elements in a .pptx that I'm modifying using the **OpenXmlSDK**.

To explain briefly, I need to embed an chart code into each image that is loaded into the presentation. It's so that the presentation can be re-uploaded and the charts can be generated again then replaced using the newest data.

Initially I was using **Extended Attributes** on the **OpenXmlElement** itself:

```
//OpenXmlDrawing = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing

// there's only one image per slide for now, so I just grab the blip which contains the image
OpenXmlDrawing.Blip blip = slidePart.Slide.Descendants<OpenXmlDrawing.Blip>().FirstOrDefault(); 

//then apply the attribute
blip.SetAttribute(new OpenXmlAttribute("customAttribute", null, customAttributeValue));
```

The issue with that being, when the .pptx is edited in PowerPoint 2013, it strips out all the Extended Attributes.

**SO.**
I've read in multiple places now that the solution is to use a CustomXmlPart.
So I was trying to find how to do it.. and it was looking like it would require me to have a separate file for each CustomXmlPart to feed into the part. Ex/

```
var customXmlPart = slidePart.AddCustomXmlPart(CustomXmlPartType.CustomXml);

using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
{
    customXmlPart.FeedData(stream);
}
```

^ and that would need to be repeated with a different file for each CustomXmlPart. Which then means I'd likely just have to have a template file containing a skeleton custom XML part, and then dynamically fill in its contents for each individual slide before feeding it into the custom xml part.

It seems like a heck of a lot of work just to put in a little custom attribute. But I haven't been able to find any alternative methods.

Can anyone please either confirm that this is indeed the way I should do it, or point me in another direction? Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes! :)

```
public class CustomXMLPropertyClass
{
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
    public string PropertyValue { get; set; }
}

private static void AddCustomXmlPartCustomPropertyToSlidePart(string propertyName, string propertyValue, SlidePart part)
{
    var customXmlPart = part.AddCustomXmlPart(CustomXmlPartType.CustomXml);

    var customProperty = new CustomXMLPropertyClass{ PropertyName = propertyName, PropertyValue = propertyValue };


    var serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(customProperty.GetType());
    var stream = new MemoryStream();

    serializer.Serialize(stream, customProperty);

    var customXml = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());

    using ( var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(customXmlPart.GetStream()))
    {
        streamWriter.Write(customXml);
        streamWriter.Flush();
    }
}
```

and then to get it back out:

```
private static string GetCustomXmlPropertyFromCustomXmlPart(CustomXmlPart customXmlPart)
{
    var customXmlProperty = new CustomXMLPropertyClass();
    string xml = "";

    using (var stream = customXmlPart.GetStream())
    {
        var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream);
        xml = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }

    using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
    {
        var serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(customXmlProperty));
        customXmlProperty = (CustomXMLPropertyClass)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }

    var customPropertyValue = customXmlProperty.PropertyValue;

    return customPropertyValue;
}
```

Comment: **NOTE:** With this method, the changes are still erased by PowerPoint 2013, so I'm working having them persist through when the presentation is edited.

Comment: Here's another question I've opened to try and deal with the issue of the custom data being erased. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50879524/how-can-i-use-custom-xml-in-pptx-so-powerpoint-2013-wont-wipe-it

Answer (score 0):

You could also try [custom properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/PowerPoint-VBA/articles/presentation-customdocumentproperties-property-powerpoint). Custom XML files are meant for complex objects, and it sounds like you only need to store simple information.